# Google Sheet Sync Firebase Cloud Functions Problems

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I have followed the readme document(link here) : https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/google-sheet-sync.
As per readme it's mentioned that:

> 1. Configure your Google API client ID and secret by running: firebase
>      functions:config:set googleapi.client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
>      googleapi.client_secret="YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
> 2. Create a new Google
>      Sheet, and copy the long string in the middle of the Sheet URL. This
>      is the Spreadsheet ID.
> 3. Configure your Google Spreadsheet ID by
>      running: firebase functions:config:set
>      googleapi.sheet_id="YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID"

So I just have written a code
in index.js as attached file below.

```
    'use strict';

// Sample trigger function that copies new Firebase data to a Google Sheet

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
var {googleapi} = require('googleapis');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.database();

// TODO: Use firebase functions:config:set to configure your googleapi object:
functions:config:set googleapi.client_id = "[REDACTED]"
functions:config:set googleapi.client_secret = "[REDACTED]"
functions:config:set googleapi.sheet_id = "[REDACTED]"
```

And also i have attached the pic of the code and the error I am getting in the cmd prompt
[image: redacted keys]

Please help me resolve the issue.
I am new to node js and to firebase cloud functions

Comment: Couple of things, never provide client_secret & client_id values. You'll need to change these on your end. Second, don't provide screenshots of errors, provide the text instead. Read through the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

The section below `// TODO: Use firebase functions:config:set to configure your googleapi object:` is not JavaScript. These commands are to set the variables from the commandline. This is not JS code.

The readme you've linked to states you need to run the commands, not put them inside your JS.

The [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/google-sheet-sync/functions/index.js) shows how to get these variables from inside your code:

```
// TODO: Use firebase functions:config:set to configure your googleapi object:
// googleapi.client_id = Google API client ID,
// googleapi.client_secret = client secret, and
// googleapi.sheet_id = Google Sheet id (long string in middle of sheet URL)
const CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = functions.config().googleapi.client_id;
const CONFIG_CLIENT_SECRET = functions.config().googleapi.client_secret;
const CONFIG_SHEET_ID = functions.config().googleapi.sheet_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. have another thread can u please help me out there link is:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656093/firebase-cloud-functions-limit-children